# Snap.svg: How to programmactically cancel an ongoing drag operation?

Tags: snap.svg

How do you cancel a drag operation in Snap.svg?
I've checked the [Docs](http://snapsvg.io/docs/) and the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/snapsvg) but didn't find anything useful.

Currently, I'm setting a `var` indicating that the operation is to be canceled, revert the effect and `return` out of every `dragMove` callback until the drag operation really ends.

What I'm looking for is a way to cancel the currently ongoing drag operation itself so no more callbacks are called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

element.undrag() should do it.

[docs](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.undrag)

Comment: This would remove the drag handlers, which is not what I want. I'm looking for a way to cancel an ongoing drag&drop operation. I'll update my question to clarify. But thanks for your reply ;)

Comment: could you create your own handler with a flag, using http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-drag as a base ?

Comment: That's what I did ;) But there doesn't (at least to me) seem to be a way of cancelling the current drag operation...

Comment: Not quite sure what you are after, if you have a handler it will operate. So you can either, remove the handler, or make the handler do nothing. Not sure what else you are after. A drag isn't an operation as such, its a handler thats triggered upon some event if that makes sense.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, thanks for your input :) I'll stick with the "make the handler do nothing" implementation.